# What is the simplest way to visualize $S^5$ - the five-dimensional sphere?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

What is the simplest way to visualize the five-dimensional sphere $S^5$? In particular, is there some 3-d object that visualizes it?

Is the following proposal correct?

A cube is suspended in mid air with rubber wires inside a hollow glass sphere.
The suspended cube with all its orientations realizes $S^3$ (or SU(2), the double cover of SO(3)). The glass sphere is swimming on water and rotating. The rotation axis of the glass sphere has two angles describing its orientation in space. Is this $S^5$ or is it $S^3 \times S^2$?

This earlier proposal is wrong, and is not an example for $S^5$:

Does a cube orbiting at a distance around a fixed axis (2 angles for the direction of the axis in 3d, plus three angles for the orientation of the cube in space) provide a visualization? The system has 5 parameters, but is the topology correct? No!  $S^5 \neq S^3 \times S^2$; furthermore, as Malkoun points out below, the cube does not even realize $S^3$, but only SO(3).

Comment: Visualise $S^n$ and then take $n=5$. :-)

Comment: Yes, that is a famous joke. I forgot to see it coming :-)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the configuration space that you described has the topology $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^3$, which is not homeomorphic to $S^5$.

Comment: For me the easiest way to visualize $S^n$ is to think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and add a point at infinity (the so-called Alexandroff one-point compactification), but I think you are looking for a different kind of model.

Comment: @Malkoun Yes, I am looking for a "tangible" model, one that can be touched.

Comment: @Malkoun Why RP^3 ? Can you explain ? I'm not a mathematician...(Isn't the group of rotations of a cube equal to S^3? - But then, I heard that S^3 x S^2 is not S5)

Comment: The space of all "orientations" of the cube in space is a manifold, known as $SO(3)$, which is the space of all orthogonal $3$ by $3$ matrices with determinant $1$. This can be thought of as right-handed orthonormal frames in $\mathbb{R}^3$. $SO(3)$ is known to be diffeomorphic to $S^3$ with antipodal points identified, and the latter is diffeomorphic to real projective $3$-space. I can provide some proofs if you want, but the space in the comments is not enough (sorry, I could not help but make this joke).

Comment: $SO(3)$ can be thought of as the manifold of all rotations moving the standard $i$, $j$, $k$ frame to some right-handed orthonormal frame. A rotation can be described by an oriented axis, described by a unit vector $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and an angle $\theta$, which can be assumed to be in $[0,\pi]$. For $\theta = 0$, you only have the identity. For $\theta \in (0, \pi)$, you get a $2$-sphere, and for $\theta = \pi$, you get a $2$-sphere with antipodal points identified, since a rotation with respect to $u$ by $\pi$ is the same as the rotation with respect to $-u$ by $\pi$.

Comment: So $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to a closed $3$-ball with the antipodal points on the boundary $2$-sphere identified. This is known to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3$. My favorite proof though, which also gives that $SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3$, uses unit quaternions, which are themselves diffeomorphic to $S^3$, and which form a double cover of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Thank you for the jokes and the explanation. I amended the question with a new proposal. Is this better?

Answer (score 1):

How about this for a tangible model:

Take five points on the number line, named R, Y, G, B, V and colored Red, Yellow,  Green, Blue, Violet. Let those points move around independently on the number line. Each possible configuration of those points (including a configuration where some of them coincide) represents a point of $\mathbb R^5$: the coordinates of a particular configuration are $(x_R,x_Y,x_G,x_B,x_V) \in \mathbb R^5$ where $R$ is located at $x_R$ on the numberline, $Y$ is located at $x_Y$ on the number line, and so on.

Roughly speaking, any time that you have a movable object (such as a configuration of points on the number line), you can count the independent number of parameters of that object (such as the five coordinates of the configuration of R, Y, G, B, and V). That number is the dimension of the configuration space of the object. That said, even when that dimension is equal to $5$, one might get some other kind of 5-dimensional manifold instead of $\mathbb R^5$; but at least locally the configuration space will look like $\mathbb R^5$.

Here's an object with a configuration space that is locally 5-dimensional: in the Cartesian coordinate plane, the union of a line segment $L$ and a ray $R$ meeting at a common endpoint $p$. The position of $p$ has two coordinates $x_p,y_p$; the other endpoint $q$ of $L$ has two more coordinates $x_q,y_q$; and the angle $\theta$ at the point $p$ between the line segment $L$ and the ray $R$ gives a fifth coordinate.

Here's an exercise: build a model of the human hand and count the number of independent parameters.

For example, here's a rather overly simplified model. If we think of the handbones and knuckles as having fixed positions, and if we think of a knuckle as only being able to bend in one dimension (not in two dimensions as my own knuckles seem to be able to bend, then: the thumb has 2 angular parameters (bend at the knuckle and the one joint), and each of the 4 fingers has 3 angular parameters (bend at the knuckle and at each of the 2 joints), for a total of $2 + 4 \times 3 = 14$ parameters. So, that model is 14 dimensional, and gives a tangible local model of $\mathbb R^{14}$...

... although, I suppose you can't touch it because it's your own hand, and how does one hand touch itself?

Comment: Thank you! That is pretty. It does not give the topology of $S^5$ though, but it is pretty, and tangible.

Comment: But it does give the topology of $S^5$, take the 1 point compactification.

Answer (score 0):

One way how you could get $S^5$ is to consider first $\mathbb{R}^6 \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$, and to identify two points in the latter manifold if they differ by a positive scaling factor.

I know you want something very concrete, possibly related to $3$-dimensional geometry. I guess one can think of the following example.

The position and velocity of a particle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is parametrized by a pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and thus by a point in $\mathbb{R}^6$. Suppose you assume that the particle does not sit still at the origin, i.e. that it is not both at the origin and with zero velocity vector. Under this assumption, the configuration space is $\mathbb{R}^6 \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$. Now there are many units to measure distances/lengths, that are proportional to each other. Suppose we would like quantities that are independent of units of lengths, then we are led to identify two configurations that differ by a positive scaling factor. The configuration space is then $S^5$.

It is a kind of artificial example, but hopefully it satisfies the OP's criteria?